# Find and replace multiple substitution using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file in which some lines aren't formatted the same way as the others. To be more precise: In this type of lines, fields are written on 9 characters, whereas on the other lines, fields are 7 characters length. Format of a (misformatted) line being:
1st field on 40 characters, then 4 spaces, then 1 character (field named note, for example letter 'a', space ' ' or letter 'b'), then 4 spaces. The preceding sequence 4 spaces+1 character+4 spaces (example below) being repeated a number of times:

> ```
>     a
> ```

Such a line would for example be:

> ```
>                                             a        a        a        a        a        c        b        a        a        a        a        a
> ```

Due to the specificity of these lines, I get an offset between lines:

> ```
>                                            26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26    
>                                             a        a        a        a        a        c        b        a        a        a        a
> ```

I would like to get rid of 2 unwanted spaces, so that on my line, a field would become 7 characters wide, as in others:
1st field on 40 characters, then 3 spaces, then 1 character (field named note, for example letter 'a'), then 3 spaces.

I can "find" such a line using the regex find in Notepad++:

> ```
> Find what : ^ {40}(( {4})(?<note>.)( {4}))+
> ```

But how do I replace all utterances of the 4 spaces+1 character+4 spaces by 3 spaces+1 character+3 spaces, so that fields on every line have the same length?

The desired format, after substitution, would for example be:

> ```
>                                            26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26  
>                                            a      a      a      a      a      c      b      a      a      a      a
> ```

Here is a larger extract of the offset file:

> ```
> 20/03/2018
> H0917    26_LAV  0 Semaine     2 En service le 04 Septembre 2017 - TAD Partiel                                    11/07/2017 16:09 H0917     
> Vertical           Notes
> Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillargu                                                 Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillarguet                             
> Montpellier Occitanie                                                                    Montpellier Occitanie                                                  
>  26  Occitanie - Montferrier-sur-Lez          26  Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de BaillarguMontpellier Occitanie                                       Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillarguet                  
> ########## VOYAGES
>  0 Semaine    Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillarguet                  
>                                            26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26   
>                                                                                          a        a        a        a        a        c        b        a        a        a        a        a                                                                       a        a        a        a        a        
>
> Occitanie                                 6:50   7:20   7:50   8:20   8:50   9:30  10:10  10:40  11:10  11:40  12:10  12:10  12:40  13:10  13:40  14:10  14:40  15:10  15:40  16:10  16:40  17:10  17:40  18:10  18:40  19:10  19:40  20:10  20:40  
> Lycée Frédéric Bazille                    6:58   7:28   7:58   8:28   8:58   9:37  10:17  10:47  11:17  11:47  12:17  12:17  12:47  13:17  13:47  14:18  14:48  15:18  15:48  16:18  16:49  17:19  17:49  18:19  18:49  19:18  19:47  20:17  20:47  
> La Lironde                                7:02   7:32   8:02   8:35   9:05   9:42  10:22  10:52  11:22  11:52  12:23  12:23  12:52  13:22  13:52  14:23  14:53  15:23  15:53  16:23  16:56  17:26  17:56  18:26  18:56  19:23  19:52  20:22  20:52  
> Chemin Neuf                               7:07   7:37   8:07   8:40   9:10   9:47  10:27  10:57  11:27  11:57  12:28  12:28  12:57  13:27  13:57  14:28  14:58  15:28  15:58  16:28  17:01  17:31  18:01  18:31  19:01  19:28  19:57  20:27  20:57  
> La Grand Font                             7:08   7:38   8:08   8:41   9:11   9:48  10:28  10:58  11:28  11:58  12:29  12:29  12:58  13:28  13:58  14:29  14:59  15:29  15:59  16:29  17:02  17:32  18:02  18:32  19:02  19:29  19:58  20:28  20:58  
> Picadou                                   7:09   7:39   8:09   8:42   9:12   9:49  10:29  10:59  11:29  11:59  12:30  12:30  12:59  13:29  13:59  14:30  15:00  15:30  16:00  16:30  17:03  17:33  18:03  18:33  19:03  19:30  19:59  20:29  20:59  
> Distillerie                               7:11   7:41   8:11   8:44   9:14   9:51  10:31  11:01  11:31  12:01  12:32  12:32  13:01  13:31  14:01  14:32  15:02  15:32  16:02  16:32  17:05  17:35  18:05  18:35  19:05  19:32  20:01  20:31  21:01  
> Cirad de Baillarguet                      7:14   7:44   8:14   8:47   9:17   9:54  10:34  11:04  11:34  12:04  12:35  12:35  13:04  13:34  14:04  14:35  15:05  15:35  16:05  16:35  17:08  17:38  18:08  18:38  19:08  19:35  20:04  20:34  21:04
> ```

Correct file should be:

> ```
> 20/03/2018
> H0917    26_LAV  0 Semaine     2 En service le 04 Septembre 2017 - TAD Partiel                                    11/07/2017 16:09 H0917     
> Vertical           Notes
> Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillargu                                                 Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillarguet                             
> Montpellier Occitanie                                                                    Montpellier Occitanie                                                  
>  26  Occitanie - Montferrier-sur-Lez          26  Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de BaillarguMontpellier Occitanie                                       Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillarguet                  
> ########## VOYAGES
>  0 Semaine    Montferrier-sur-Lez - Cirad de Baillarguet                  
>                                            26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26     26   
>                                                                               a      a      a      a      a      c      b      a      a      a      a      a                                                       a      a      a      a      a        
>
> Occitanie                                 6:50   7:20   7:50   8:20   8:50   9:30  10:10  10:40  11:10  11:40  12:10  12:10  12:40  13:10  13:40  14:10  14:40  15:10  15:40  16:10  16:40  17:10  17:40  18:10  18:40  19:10  19:40  20:10  20:40  
> Lycée Frédéric Bazille                    6:58   7:28   7:58   8:28   8:58   9:37  10:17  10:47  11:17  11:47  12:17  12:17  12:47  13:17  13:47  14:18  14:48  15:18  15:48  16:18  16:49  17:19  17:49  18:19  18:49  19:18  19:47  20:17  20:47  
> La Lironde                                7:02   7:32   8:02   8:35   9:05   9:42  10:22  10:52  11:22  11:52  12:23  12:23  12:52  13:22  13:52  14:23  14:53  15:23  15:53  16:23  16:56  17:26  17:56  18:26  18:56  19:23  19:52  20:22  20:52  
> Chemin Neuf                               7:07   7:37   8:07   8:40   9:10   9:47  10:27  10:57  11:27  11:57  12:28  12:28  12:57  13:27  13:57  14:28  14:58  15:28  15:58  16:28  17:01  17:31  18:01  18:31  19:01  19:28  19:57  20:27  20:57  
> La Grand Font                             7:08   7:38   8:08   8:41   9:11   9:48  10:28  10:58  11:28  11:58  12:29  12:29  12:58  13:28  13:58  14:29  14:59  15:29  15:59  16:29  17:02  17:32  18:02  18:32  19:02  19:29  19:58  20:28  20:58  
> Picadou                                   7:09   7:39   8:09   8:42   9:12   9:49  10:29  10:59  11:29  11:59  12:30  12:30  12:59  13:29  13:59  14:30  15:00  15:30  16:00  16:30  17:03  17:33  18:03  18:33  19:03  19:30  19:59  20:29  20:59  
> Distillerie                               7:11   7:41   8:11   8:44   9:14   9:51  10:31  11:01  11:31  12:01  12:32  12:32  13:01  13:31  14:01  14:32  15:02  15:32  16:02  16:32  17:05  17:35  18:05  18:35  19:05  19:32  20:01  20:31  21:01  
> Cirad de Baillarguet                      7:14   7:44   8:14   8:47   9:17   9:54  10:34  11:04  11:34  12:04  12:35  12:35  13:04  13:34  14:04  14:35  15:05  15:35  16:05  16:35  17:08  17:38  18:08  18:38  19:08  19:35  20:04  20:34  21:04
> ```

Thanks for helping,
Julien

Comment: Why don't you replace all occurrences of `a\s*` with `a       `? (I.e. `a` followed by any amount of spaces with an `a` followed by exactly 7 spaces.)

Comment: Probably `(?<!\S) {4}(\S) {4}(?!\S)` -> `<3spaces>$1<3spaces>`.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your proposal but since the note field can also be a space character as I indicated, those won't match. Also, if I allow these 9 spaces to match without taking into account the rest of the line, other spaces strings will match and be substituted by Replace All.

Comment: Sorry, I meant thanks Wiktor.

Comment: Also, since Adam edited my question, the displayed format doesn't represent the text file I'm facing anymore.

Comment: I've rolled back to the original version of my post. I hope it will make it clearer (at least example are coherent with description).

Comment: Are you using a monospaced font? If not, then you'll never get it perfect.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, I'm using a monospaced font. In fact the offset it's not much a problem of render/appearance but rather that I can't assume a fixed length format and for example convert to delimited.

Comment: @Julien I took a look it the pattern of the 2 rows and the pattern is hard to follow, If there's one letter under every 26 heading, it'd be easier `/(\S{6})/g` `$1` *untested*.

Comment: @zer00ne The format is how I described it: start with 40 spaces, then 9 characters made of 4 spaces, 1 character (a letter or a space), 4 spaces, then 9 characters and so on. It's how I get the file from our tool, unfortunately I have no power on it...

Comment: @Julien If the times had zero padding, every column would be exactly 5 spaces for the 26 row and 6 spaces for the letter row. Would it be ok to pad the times? ex.`09:59` Notice how that particular row stops short of the columns with the 3 digit times?

Comment: I see your problem now. This cannot be done with a regex as far as I know (it almost could, the problem is the "empty" fields.) There is a script plugin for notepad++ that could work (or an external script) or if you control generation of the file you could try that.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks kabanus for taking a deep look at my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but this got things aligned for me:

```
 ([^ ]) 
\1
```

Note there is one space before and **one after** the parenthesis. This removes one space before and one after each single non-space character. It ignores the 26s since those are two non-space characters, so replace all works.

Comment: Thanks Gary. But I need to replace the sequence of 4 space characters, 1 character (a letter or a space), 4 space characters by 3 space characters, 1 character, 3 space characters, only when it occurs in a line beginning with 40 space characters and then only such sequences are found on the same line. I've reverted to the original version of my post since edits made by Adam made it incoherent.

Comment: @Julien Ah, I see. Good to know, makes sense now. I'll have a look later.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion though? If the offset lines have one character words only, and the good lines have 2, it would still work.

Comment: If it doesn't, I suggest you post a larger snippet of your file.

Comment: As you suggested I updated my question to add a larger extract of the file with offset and the result I would expect.

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion. It doesn't fit my need since there are also spaces (as well as single characters) in between series of 4 spaces.